Creating new columns by generating a multiples of 2
I have a data frame of multiple columns. I want to select the first column and produce 7 more by multiplying the first column in multiples of 2. Help out, please
I tried creating more columns, but the data is not transferred to the new columns.

Be explicit, provide a [mre] of your data and the matching expected output

Assuming such an input:
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [1,2,3,10]})

An efficient approach would be to use numpy broadcasting:
import numpy as np

N = 7
nums = 2**np.arange(1, N+1)
out = df.join(pd.DataFrame(
    df.iloc[:, 0].to_numpy()[:,None]*nums,
    index=df.index, columns=nums
   ).rename(columns=lambda x: f'*{x}')
)

print(out)

As commented by @HenryEcker, a variant to perform the broadcasting would be to use numpy.multiply.outer:
N = 7
nums = 2**np.arange(1, N+1)
out = df.join(pd.DataFrame(
    np.multiply.outer(df.iloc[:, 0].to_numpy(), nums),
    index=df.index, columns=nums
   ).rename(columns=lambda x: f'*{x}')
)

Output:
   col  *2  *4  *8  *16  *32  *64  *128
0    1   2   4   8   16   32   64   128
1    2   4   8  16   32   64  128   256
2    3   6  12  24   48   96  192   384
3   10  20  40  80  160  320  640  1280


This is mostly for some future reader, np.multiply.outer(df.iloc[:, 0].to_numpy(), nums) is functionally equivalent to df.iloc[:, 0].to_numpy()[:,None]*nums but might be a bit less opaque when reading the code for those less comfortable than mozway with broadcasting. You could also build this off the original DataFrame if you wanted/needed to df.loc[:, [f'*{x}' for x in nums]] = np.multiply.outer(df.iloc[:, 0].to_numpy(), nums)

@Henry that's a good point, I have to admit I'm used to think in terms of dimensions so I don't always think it's not so easy. I'll update the answer a bit later.

Not sure if I get your question right, but here is an example:
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],  # first column
    'B': [5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
    'C': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

first_column = df['A']

# new columns by multiplying by 2, 4, 6, ..., 14
for i in range(1, 8):
    df[f'A_{i*2}'] = first_column * (i * 2)

print(df)

Result:
   A  B   C  A_2  A_4  A_6  A_8  A_10  A_12  A_14
0  1  5  10    2    4    6    8    10    12    14
1  2  4  20    4    8   12   16    20    24    28
2  3  3  30    6   12   18   24    30    36    42
3  4  2  40    8   16   24   32    40    48    56
4  5  1  50   10   20   30   40    50    60    70

UPDATE (After mozway comment! thx.):
User Polars for larger Dataframes.
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
    'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'B': [5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
    'C': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
})

first_column = df['A']

multipliers = range(2, 16, 2)  # Creates [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14]
expressions = [first_column * multiplier for multiplier in multipliers]

df = df.with_columns([
    (first_column * multiplier).alias(f'A_{multiplier}') for multiplier in multipliers
]) 
print(df)


Just a quick note on adding columns using a loop, this tends to be slow and to fragment the DataFrame.

@mozway: absolutely right. I updated the code for larger dataframes. thx.

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


data = {'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

cols = [f'2^{i}' for i in range(1, 8)]
df[cols] = df['col1'].values[:, None] * 2**np.arange(1, 8)
#OR
#df[cols] = df['col1'].values[:, np.newaxis] * 2**np.arange(1, 8)

print(df.to_string())
"""
   col1  2^1  2^2  2^3  2^4  2^5  2^6  2^7
0     1    2    4    8   16   32   64  128
1     2    4    8   16   32   64  128  256
2     3    6   12   24   48   96  192  384
3     4    8   16   32   64  128  256  512
4     5   10   20   40   80  160  320  640
"""

